# Exclude range from SheetBeforeDoubleClick event

Tags: excel, vba

How can I exclude a range from the SheetBeforeDoubleClick event? I have tried this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetToExclude").ListObjects("TableToExclude").ListColumns("ColumnToExclude").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The (truncated) sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim DV As Validation, RngDV As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Validation.Type <> 3 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set RngDV = Range(Target.Address)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not RngDV Is Nothing Then
        ~
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case True
        ~
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It is at the end of the sub? That means the sub will run anyway and then at the end this condition will be checked.

Comment: Might be more useful to show the rest of the method.

Comment: Note that `RngDV = Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `RngDV = Target` don't make it more complicated as it needs to be. `Target` is already declared as a range `ByVal Target As Range`. • You say *"I have tried this"* but you don't explain what was wrong with your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code here …

> ```
> If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetToExclude").ListObjects("TableToExclude").ListColumns("ColumnToExclude").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
>     Exit Sub
> End If
> ```

… is, that if `Target` is not in the worksheet `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetToExclude")` the code will throw an error because you cannot intersect ranges accross multiple worksheets. All ranges that you try to intersect need to be in the same worksheet.

So you first need to test if the sheet `sh` (where your `Target` is in) is the same worksheet as your range to exclude is in. You can do this by comparing their names:

```
If Sh.Name = ShExclude.Name Then
```

And if they are the same worksheet then you can try to intersect:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RangeExclude) Is Nothing Then
```

So you end up with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ShExclude As Worksheet
    Set ShExclude = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetToExclude")

    Dim RangeExclude As Range
    Set RangeExclude = ShExclude.ListObjects("TableToExclude").ListColumns("ColumnToExclude").DataBodyRange

    If Sh.Name = ShExclude.Name Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RangeExclude) Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'code here will run for all cells except the ones in RangeExclude
    MsgBox "Double Clicked"
End Sub
```